# Postman POST request works but running a collection on the same request returns 422 error

Tags: api, post, postman

I'm currently working on testing my API via Postman and I've noticed that when I send a post request to the endpoint it will successfully send, yet the same POST request will return a "422 Unprocessable entity" error when run as a collection. The 422 error is puzzling to me because syntactically everything checks out. I'm having a hard time understanding what may be the issue here between running the request as a collection versus without doing so, any thoughts on what the issue might be here?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why a request with an attached file fails when run as a collection is probably the location of the attachment. Files uploaded through `form-data` must be placed in the working directory. Otherwise, the collection runner won't locate them and will send a request with no files attached. This results in *422*. It's different from executing individual requests where files can be placed inside any directory.

This issue is also present in *newman* and can be similarly solved by specifying a working directory with `--working-dir` and placing files inside of that directory.